# Composite Templates and RoutingOrder - Nothing for second signer

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I have been experimenting with the DocuSign eSign C# library, and everything has been working as expected for single template envelopes. I now need to use 2 different templates within a single envelope and have run into some issues.

I have 2 templates that I wish to combine. Everything works exactly as expected when I create a composite template, add the necessary recipients, and send the notification. This sends the combined templates to both recipients in parallel.

As soon as I add a RoutingOrder of 1/2 to the recipients, the first recipient gets prompted to sign as expected, and then once signed it is passed on to the second recipient. **This is where the problem lies...** the second recipient doesn't have any tabs to fill in and/or any place to sign.

If I switch the RoutingOrder of the recipients, I get the same behavior, so it is definitely related to a person being the second recipient.

Any thoughts on what I can do to fix this are greatly appreciated! The JSON generated by the DocuSign eSign API can be found below:

```
{
  "eventNotification": {
    "url": "<my_webhook_callback_url>",
    "loggingEnabled": "true",
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "envelopeEvents": [
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent" },
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "delivered" },
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed" },
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "declined" },
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "voided" }
    ],
  "recipientEvents": [
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Sent" },
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Delivered" },
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed" },
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "Declined" },
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "AuthenticationFailed" },
    { "recipientEventStatusCode": "AutoResponded" }
  ],
  "useSoapInterface": "false",
  "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
  "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
  "includeDocuments": "true",
  "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "true",
  "includeTimeZone": "true",
  "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
  "includeDocumentFields": "true",
  "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "true"
  },
  "compositeTemplates": [
  {
    "serverTemplates": [
      {
        "sequence": "1",
        "templateId": "1b5230a2-15da-4502-8ea4-9a7a28ae02aa"
      } 
    ],
    "inlineTemplates": [
      {
        "sequence": "1",
        "recipients": {
          "signers": [
            {
              "name": "<customer_signer_name>",
              "email": "<customer_signer_name>",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "routingOrder": "1",
              "roleName": "Customer"
            },
            {
              "name": "<internal_signer_name>",
              "email": "<internal_signer_email>",
              "recipientId": "2",
              "routingOrder": "2",
              "roleName": "InternalSigner"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "serverTemplates": [
      {
        "sequence": "1",
        "templateId": "ae08ac4b-2d92-43cc-9c18-5eaa0a6cc8c7"
      }
    ],
    "inlineTemplates": [
      {
        "sequence": "1",
        "recipients": {
          "signers": [
            {
              "name": "<customer_signer_name>",
              "email": "<customer_signer_name>",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "routingOrder": "1",
              "roleName": "Customer"
            },
            {
              "name": "<internal_signer_name>",
              "email": "<internal_signer_email>",
              "recipientId": "2",
              "routingOrder": "2",
              "roleName": "InternalSigner"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Test Email Subject"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server templates have both the recipients at routing order 1. Since the inlineTemplates specify the recipient at routing Order 2, the tabs in the server template will not be associated with the recipient at routing order 2.

> **Recipient matching** is based on Recipient Role and Routing Order. If there are matches, the recipient information is merged together. A final pass is done on all CompositeTemplates, after all template overlays have been applied, to collapse recipients with the same email, username and routing order. This prevents having the same recipients at the same routing order.

You will have to either update the routing order of the recipient on your server template or specify tabs in the inline template.

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing. I thought the routing order had been set within the template, but it had not. Thank you!